# Video grain resolved by changing keyboard USB hub

Tags: graphics-card, display, keyboard, cpu, motherboard

[RESOLVED]

For the past couple of days my screen has been grainy and when the volume is turned up there is noise, I usually simply reboot to clear it but the frequency has increased. It also affects my keyboard and mouse repeating input and printing random characters. I don't think it is my monitor/TV because other components are being affected. I am on HDMI if that helps any.

I am now being displayed No Signal on the screen and the computer shuts down minutes after boot up. I am unable to use it. The last times it happened I had task manager open and saw no change in CPU usage. My motherboard and CPU are new, the video card is at least three years old. Finally, the power supply (12-volt) levels were not below their indicated average.

Edit: The video card is not the problem.

Edit 2: Also not the motherboard. It was the USB hub that my keyboard was plugged into. Glad I didn't waste money on any functioning components.

Pictures of grain:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like a failing video card, if your CPU has video capability, try running without the video card installed or borrow a video card to see if it resolves. Also, check the heat sink(s) and fan on the video card. I have seen a small "dust bunny" stuck in the heat sink cause mild overheating which presented very similarly to this.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what make/model your graphics card is but this is very clearly the card failing.

Comment: Burgi, Yorik, it was not the GPU. I have an AMD CPU that runs graphics on it as well as the GPU I took out of the tower.

Comment: These symptoms indicate, to me, a faulty motherboard that's degrading further over time. Can you RMA the motherboard?

Comment: keyboard printing random characters along with graphics issue?! that is quite the problem!

Comment: Fixed it! Read the edit. The fix came from my dad; he's worked on computers for 35+ years.